# Tmap: Cannot create school district map for national level

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap, usmap

I want to plot school districts on a national map in *R* using the library *Tmap*. I used a shapefile from the [official website](https://nces.ed.gov/programs/edge/Geographic/DistrictBoundaries), *the National Center for Education Statistics*, for school district boundaries. Please note that I used the 2019 file instead of the latest one, and you can download this file from *Single Composite File* in the link mentioned earlier. I first tried with one state, Utah, and everything went well without any problems. My code to plot this map and the reference for the national map ([from Bloomberg Citylab](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-22/an-interactive-map-from-edbuild-shows-how-school-district-funding-enforces-poverty-rates)) is following;

```
library (sf)
library (tmap)
map <- st_read(".../schooldistrict_sy1819_tl19.shp")
ut <- map[map$STATEFP == 49, ]
tm_shape(ut) + tm_borders()
```

[image]
[image]

However, I encountered an error when I tried to make the national map. I used this code and got the following error.

```
tm_shape(map) + tm_borders()
Error: Shape contains invalid polygons. Please fix it or set tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE) and rerun the plot
```

Of course, I did some research. One website suggested that the following error occurred because of invalid geometries. I checked and tried to make these valid, but I got the same mistake as the first time I did. I attempted to solve this problem with the following code.

```
sum(!st_is_valid(map$geometry))
[1] 858
st_make_valid(map$geometry)
Geometry set for 13315 features 
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -179.1686 ymin: -14.5487 xmax: 179.7487 ymax: 71.38961
Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.11417 26.07902, -80.11423 2...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.19919 26.77353, -82.19748 2...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.45356 25.80323, -81.45388 2...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.39962 25.25725, -80.40002 2...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.56409 27.34066, -81.56423 2...
 
tm_shape(map) + tm_borders()
Error: Shape contains invalid polygons. Please fix it or set tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE) and rerun the plot
```

Since I was blank about the geometry in R, I totally have no idea how to make it works. If anyone has done this before, could you please share any advice/ suggestions regarding this? Any idea to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thank you so much for reading my question!

Comment: Doesn't `st_make_valid` need to be saved or assigned?  Looks like you returned the valid geometry (to the console) and tried to use the original `map` data that still contains the invalid geometries.

Comment: @mrhellmann Thank you! this is an excellent observation. Let me try this real quick. It would be very embarrassing if this solved the problem!

Comment: @mrhellmann and it seems like I lose face for this minor mistake. Thank you for catching this basic stuff. I appreciate it!

Comment: Everything was right except for that one small step. Happens to everyone.

Comment: And write up your adjusted/assigned code as answer and then accept it so others will be directed to a useful, working solution.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your suggestion! I took your advice and wrote my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mrhellmann, who figured out the minor mistake I made, you need to assign the map data to a new variable after using `st_make_valid`. I used the following code to plot the district-level data into the nationwide map.

```
library (SF)
library (tmap)
map <- st_read(".../schooldistrict_sy1819_tl19.shp")
map2 <- st_make_valid(map$geometry)
tm_shape(map2) + tm_borders()
```